# Need to add specific time to CTE_Dates calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, common-table-expression

I have a Dates CTE that allows me to fill in the dates between date stamped records.  (Thanks SO!) However, I need the CTE_Dates table to time stamp its "StatusDate" column with a specific time instead of '00:00:00.000' and am not quite sure how to go about ding so.  Here is the CTE_Dates code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '07/15/2017'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '07/30/2017'

;WITH cte_Dates AS 
(
SELECT        
CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, @StartDate) = 1 THEN @StartDate ELSE DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 1, @StartDate) + 1, 0) END AS StatusDate
UNION ALL
SELECT        DATEADD(Day, 1,StatusDate)
   FROM            cte_Dates
   WHERE        DATEADD(Day, 1, StatusDate) <= @EndDate
)


    --this select statement actually pulls data from 2 CTE's that are joined but represents how I am pulling the StatusDate from CTE_Dates

    select

    CASE WHEN CAST(statusDate as Date) IS NULL
        THEN LAG(cast(StatusDate  as Date)) OVER (PARTITION BY item_no ORDER BY statStart)
        ELSE StatusDate END as StatusDate,
    SELECT * from cte_dates
Results:

StatusDate
2017-07-15 00:00:00.000
2017-07-16 00:00:00.000
2017-07-17 00:00:00.000
2017-07-18 00:00:00.000
2017-07-19 00:00:00.000
2017-07-20 00:00:00.000
2017-07-21 00:00:00.000
2017-07-22 00:00:00.000
2017-07-23 00:00:00.000
2017-07-24 00:00:00.000
2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
2017-07-26 00:00:00.000
2017-07-27 00:00:00.000
2017-07-28 00:00:00.000
2017-07-29 00:00:00.000
2017-07-30 00:00:00.000
```

The CTE works great!  Except I need the timestamp to be noon...

Comment: Zorkolot - Thank you for the edit... still figuring out the post formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add time value to date like this.

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '07/15/2017'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '07/30/2017'

;WITH cte_Dates AS 
(
SELECT        
CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, @StartDate) = 1 THEN @StartDate ELSE DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 1, @StartDate) + 1, 0) END
+ '12:00'
 AS StatusDate
UNION ALL
SELECT        DATEADD(Day, 1,StatusDate)
   FROM            cte_Dates
   WHERE        DATEADD(Day, 1, StatusDate) <= @EndDate
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_Dates
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you sarslan (Simple fix I know - but very much appreciated!)

Answer (score 0):

You could use dateadd, adding 12 hours:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 12, StatusDate) AS StatusDate FROM CTE_Dates
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works on a simple select.  Which is exactly what I asked.. however, I have a Case statement in my select clause.. I will edit the question to properly reflect that and see if you can help me around the Case,Cast, etc to pull the correct Datetime.  I am limited on the code I can put here, please be patient.

Comment: Try sarslan's answer. Might take care of the issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use two CTEs:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '2017-07-15';
DECLARE @EndDate date = '2017-07-30';
DECLARE @time time = '04:00:00';

WITH cte_Dates AS (
      SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, @StartDate) = 1 THEN @StartDate ELSE DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 1, @StartDate) + 1, 0) END AS StatusDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(Day, 1,StatusDate)
      FROM            cte_Dates
      WHERE        DATEADD(Day, 1, StatusDate) <= @EndDate
     ),
     cte_DateTimes as (
      select cast(statusDate as datetime) + cast(@time as datetime)
      from cte_Dates
     )
SELECT *
FROM CTE_DateTimes;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon!  I will try this too.